# Visual puzzle with two 3x3 grids with black and white tiles added to each other to get a third

Tags: pattern, visual

I am trying to answer this visual puzzle - which of the five potential answers is correct, and why?

[image: Visual puzzle question]

Source: http://www.admissions.yildiz.edu.tr/images/files/ytuyos2018.pdf

Comment: That PDF appears to have a list of answers at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be

> a XOR operation: squares that are different in both sides are black, others are white.

and in that case, the correct answer would be

> D

Comment: I sat for ages trying to format my example - rage - well done

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is:

> D

Historical examples show that:

> Black + Black = White; White + White = White; White + Black = Black; Black + White = White